# How to use Service Account key with Simba JDBC Driver for Google Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there a way to explicitly configure a service account key for Simba JDBC Driver for Google Cloud Spanner and avoid using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest release of the driver (1.0.4.1005) appears to support an optional JDBC parameter `PvtKeyPath` which takes a path to your private key as opposed to having to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable. Worth a look.

From the included PDF documentation:

[image: PvtKeyPath]

So you will have a URL like: `jdbc:cloudspanner://;Project=...;PvtKeyPath=/path/to/credentials.json`

Answer (score 1):

Simba JDBC driver uses [standard Google auth](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#getting_credentials_for_server-centric_flow) for connecting to Cloud Spanner. So you do need to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to use a service account. Note that this is set by default on GCE VMs.

Comment: Thanks. But I am running it outside the GCP in a docker container - I have to set it explicitly.

Comment: Yes in that case setting it explicitly is the only option.

Comment: Where could I log a feature request to have Service Account file location passed on as a parameter in the JDBC URL - the way it is done for other Simba drivers (i.e. BigQuery)?

Comment: I had not realized that Bigquery driver allows this. I will explore if this can be done for Cloud Spanner driver as well. Thanks.

Comment: This solution does not allow for multiple connections with different service accounts when using the same process! Being able to parameterize the Service Account file location like BigQuery in the JDBC connection string would be a big win. If you download the BigQuery driver, it documents these richer options -- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/.

Comment: For the components I develop myself I usually offer three auth options. The default one through GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Then the custom ENV VAR that takes precedence over the the GOOGLE_. For example - APM_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. And the last is the three ENV VARs - project id, service account and the key - so the file is not required at all, the key is constructed in memory.

Comment: We have released a new version of jdbc driver which allows you to specify the path of the credential file in the URL. Please download it from: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/partners/drivers